# Labelling voltages for a transformer with CircuiTikz

Tags: circuitikz

I am drawing a rectifier circuit and I want to label the voltage across a winding of the transformer (the voltage between *A1 and A2*, also between *B1 and L2.midtap*, between *B2 and L2.midtap*). I can only label the voltage across a circuit element, but I want to label the voltage between two nodes.
[image: The voltage is expected to be labelled like this.]

[image: Also the wires looks 'unconnected' at node a and 'overstretched' around resistor R. Here's the output.]This looks quite odd and I've no idea why.

Here's my code

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american, scale=0.8]
            \ctikzset{t/.style={
                transformer core,
                inductors/width=1.8, 
                inductors/coils=8, 
                quadpoles/transformer core/height=2.4}
            }           
            \draw (0,4) node[t, anchor=A1](T){};
            \node [ocirc] at (T.A1){}; \node [ocirc] at (T.A2){};
            \draw (T-L2.midtap) to[short, -*] (T.B1 |- T-L2.midtap) node[ground]{}
            to[short,-] ++(1,0) 
            to[R=$R$,-] ++(1,0) 
            to[short,-*] ++(1,0) node[name=a]{};
            \draw (T.B1) to[D=$D_1$] (T.B1 -| a)
            --(a) --(T.B2 -| a);
            \draw (T.B2) to[D=$D_2$] (T.B2 -| a);
        \end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: See pages 133-134 of the circuitikz manual for examples of transformers labels.  Also, 1cm is not enough room for a resistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added all the labels from the example. See the tikz manual for calc labeling protocol.  There are other ways to position the nodes, but I needed to get them to line up for both circ and text.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}% includes calc

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american, scale=0.8]
            \ctikzset{t/.style={
                transformer core,
                inductors/width=1.8, 
                inductors/coils=8, 
                quadpoles/transformer core/height=2.4}
            }
            \draw (0,4) node[t, anchor=A1](T){};
            \draw (T.A1) node[below]{$+$}
              (T.A2) node[above]{$-$}
              ($(T.A1)!0.5!(T.A2)$) node{$v_I$}
              (T.outer dot A1) ++(0,0.7cm) node[circ]{}
              (T.outer dot B1) ++(0,0.7cm) node[circ]{} node[right]{$+$}
              (T.outer dot B1) node[right]{$v_S$}
              ($(T.outer dot B1)!0.4!(T.outer dot B2)$) node[right]{$-$}
              ($(T.outer dot B1)!0.6!(T.outer dot B2)$) node[circ]{} node[right]{$+$}
              (T.outer dot B2) node[right]{$v_S$}
              (T.outer dot B2) ++(0,-0.7cm) node[right]{$-$};
            \node [ocirc] at (T.A1){}; \node [ocirc] at (T.A2){};
            \draw (T-L2.midtap) to[short, -*] (T.B1 |- T-L2.midtap) node[ground]{}
              to[R=$R$,-*] ++(3,0) coordinate (a);
            \draw (T.B1) to[D=$D_1$] (T.B1 -| a)
              --(a) --(T.B2 -| a);
            \draw (T.B2) to[D=$D_2$] (T.B2 -| a);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]